handling parameters with special characters (bracket) in JSON
I have a JSON file that getting a few parameters then runs by Airflow.
The question is how can I put the given two parameters into the brackets character so.
my JSON and config files look like as below:
JSON file.
{
...
   "params": ["${TYPE.A}", "${TYPE.B}"],
...
}

config.py file.
class DotDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError as k:
            raise AttributeError(k)

TYPE = DotDict({
    "A": "A",
    "B": "B",
})

then the output comes out as ["['A'", "'B']"].
But it should be as ['A', 'B'] as I expected.
Thank you in advance.

note that JSON inherently has double-quotes

@y2k-shubham you're right. when I debug the variable with a breakpoint, it shows me with single quotes in the config file so.
